# I'm trying to host an Angular project on GitHub

Tags: angular, github, documentation, ng-build, angular-cli-ghpages

I'm trying to host an Angular project on GitHub. I have a project called `website.github.io`, I made a `gh-pages` branch, then a dist file where only a part of my page is uploaded, and when I generate the link, the page does not appear, I used the following commands:

```
npm install -g angular-cli-ghpages
ng build --configuration production "https://github.com/GogaTsutsunava/website.github.io"
```

and finally:

```
ngh --dir dist/website.github.io
```

This is my gh-pages:
[image: this is gh-pages]

I got this result with my commands:
[image: I got this result with my commands]

This is my dist folder:
[image]

Comment: What is the URL you want your project to be hosted on? My understanding is all github pages sites are hosted as `https://<USERNAME>.github.io/<PROJECT_NAME>` which in this case looks like it would be `https://GogaTsutsunava.github.io/website.github.io` - is this what you're going for?

Comment: One thing to fix is on your `gh-pages` branch I think all your Angular files (main, polyfills, runtime, etc...) should be in the _root_ directory, not inside a folder - [like this](https://github.com/pjpscriv/day/blob/gh-pages/)